# NullPointerException generated when using setAdapter in android application

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to follow an exercise to create a simple to do list application on android but I'm getting NullPointerException when I run the project.  I can see from LogCat that it is line 46 in my code that is causing the problem but I can't see why, here' the java file:

```
package com.example.todolist;

//import android.R;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class ToDoListActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //inflate the view
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_to_do_list);


        //get references to UI widgets
        ListView myListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.myListView1);
        final EditText myEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.myEditText); //You are always allowed to initialize a final variable. The compiler makes sure that you can do it only once


        //Create the Array List of to do items
        final ArrayList<String> todoItems = new ArrayList<String>();

        //Create the Array Adaptor to bind the array to the List View
        final ArrayAdapter<String> aa;

        aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,todoItems);
        //simple_list_item_1 is a reference to an built-in XML layout document that is part of the Android OS


        //below is causing nullpointer exception
        //Bind the ArrayAdapter to the list view
        myListView.setAdapter(aa);

        /*
        myEditText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER) ||
                            (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                        todoItems.add(0,myEditText.getText().toString());
                        aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        myEditText.setText("");
                        return true;
                    }
                return false;
            }   
            });
        */

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.to_do_list, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_to_do_list,
                    container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

and here are the 2 XML layout files, firstly activity_to_do_list.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.todolist.ToDoListActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

and fragment_to_do_list.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/myEditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/addItemHint"
    />
  <ListView
    android:id="@+id/myListView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  />
</LinearLayout>
```

It is the line myListView.setAdapter(aa); which is causing the null pointer exception but I can't see why because aa has been instantiated as far as I can see.  Can anyone help please?

Comment: `myListView` is `null`

Comment: And its null because its in the fragment, not the activity xml, so it isn't found by findViewById

Comment: Just delete your fragments. You don't need to use Fragments here. Delete the fragment class and xml for that fragment. And move the `ListView` that is currently on the fragment's xml to the main xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move much of your logic from the `onCreate()` method of your activity to the `onCreateView()` of your fragment. This is because the fragment's view has not yet been inflated at the time you are trying to find the `ListView` in your activity.

Comment: Thanks so much, I moved the code to the fragment and after modifying a few rows it worked!  I needed to change the class calling the findViewById methods to that used in the fragment: rootView.findViewById(R.id.myEditText); 
   
and also the context for the ArrayAdaptor as this doesn't work in fragments:     
aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,todoItems);